# Having a local my.cnf for mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have a local my.cnf file for MySQL in which can override global one which is in `/etc/mysql`. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I installed mysql from `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Create a file called .my.cnf in your home folder.
It can look something like this:

```
[client]
host        =<MySQL server ip>
user        =user
password    =pass
```